# Add an included TColorListBox.Style color group at run-time without overwriting any existing custom colors?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, tcolor

I have a `TColorListBox` in a Delphi 10.4.2 32-bit VCL Application:

```
object ColorListBox1: TColorListBox
  Left = 0
  Top = 232
  Width = 498
  Height = 224
  Align = alBottom
  Selected = clScrollBar
  Style = [cbCustomColors]
  ItemHeight = 20
  TabOrder = 1
  ExplicitWidth = 484
end
```

I have added a few custom color items to the color list with the help of a `TColorDialog`:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if dlgColor1.Execute(Self.Handle) then
  begin
    // insert on top:
    ColorListBox1.Items.InsertObject(0, 'My Color', TObject(dlgColor1.Color));
  end;
end;
```

...with this result:

[image]

Now I try to add one of the included `TColorListBox.Style` color groups **without overwriting the previously added custom colors**:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAddGroupClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ColorListBox1.Style := ColorListBox1.Style + [cbStandardColors];
end;
```

But this OVERWRITES the previously added custom colors!

How can I add an included `TColorListBox.Style` color group like above at run-time without overwriting any existing custom colors?

(Please note that the "cbCustomColors" is included as default: `Style = [cbCustomColors]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to save the existing colors in a temporary list:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAddGroupClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  CL: TStringList;
begin
  CL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    CL.Assign(ColorListBox1.Items); // save existing colors in a temporary list
    ColorListBox1.Style := ColorListBox1.Style + [cbStandardColors];
    ColorListBox1.Items.AddStrings(CL); // now add the temporary list
  finally
    CL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

If you want to keep the existing colors on top of the list you have to insert the temporary colors one by one:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAddGroupClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not (cbStandardColors in ColorListBox1.Style) then
    AddColorGroup([cbStandardColors]);
end;

procedure TForm1.AddColorGroup(AColorGroup: TColorBoxStyle);
var
  CL: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  CL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    CL.Assign(ColorListBox1.Items); // save existing colors in a temporary list
    ColorListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      ColorListBox1.Style := ColorListBox1.Style + AColorGroup;
      // keep existing colors on top:
      for i := CL.Count - 1 downto 0 do // insert temporary colors back one by one
        ColorListBox1.Items.InsertObject(0, CL[i], CL.Objects[i]);
    finally
      ColorListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    CL.Free;
  end;
end;
```